# Unable to call onClick function in React

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, onclick, typeerror

I have a stateless functional component called `Likes`. Within it, I have two functions: `handleLikePlus()` and `handleLikeMinus()`. I want to trigger each one of them respectively when clicking on the up, or down arrows within the `Likes` component.

Here is the code for my component

```
function Likes( {likes} ) {
   function handleLikePlus() {
      this.setState({
         likes: this.state.likes + 1
      });
   };
   function handleLikeMinus() {
      this.setState({
         likes: this.state.likes - 1
      });
   };
   return (
      <div>
         <div onClick={this.handleLikePlus()}>
            <h5><i className="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></h5>
         </div>
         <div>
            <h4>{likes}</h4>
         </div>
         <div onClick={this.handleLikeMinus()}>
            <h5><i className="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h5>
         </div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

My console returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'handleLikePlus' of undefined
```

Where am I going wrong? Is it a simple syntax error? Or am I calling the function in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the whole point of stateless means no `this`. and certainly no `thie.state` and especially no `this.setState`. Stateless right? pass those functions down from a parent. also it should be `onClick={handleLikePlus}` not `onClick={handlLikePlus()}`. you're passing a function reference, not the result of calling a function

Comment: Oh man, that was stupid... <facepalm>. Clue's in the name, right? :) So, solution is pass it from a parent. Also very useful to know that it is a function **reference** as opposed to a function **call**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a stateless component, but you're still trying to use `setState()` — that won't work. If you need state, use a normal component.

Also, as the error reads, `handleLikePlus` cannot be accessed from `this`, since there is no `this` inside your function.